# How to get height and width of a div container in react when i am resizing it using CSS resize property

Tags: reactjs

height and width of a div container in react when I am resizing it using CSS resize property
I have tried this but i am getting error

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
const TextAreaWrapper = () => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ height: 0, width: 0 });
  const textareaRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const textarea = textareaRef.current;

    const handleResize = () => {
        console.log('Hello world');
      setDimensions({
        height: textarea.offsetHeight,
        width: textarea.offsetWidth,
      });
    };
    textarea.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => {
      textarea.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea ref={textareaRef} />
      <p>Height: {dimensions.height}</p>
      <p>Width: {dimensions.width}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default TextAreaWrapper;
```

Comment: Please specify what error you are getting.

Comment: On Resize the textarea , need to get height and Width Every Time

Answer (score 1):

Try this (check that the ref is not null):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const textarea = textareaRef.current;
    
    if (!textarea) {
       return;
    }

    const handleResize = () => {
      setDimensions({
        height: textarea.offsetHeight,
        width: textarea.offsetWidth,
      });
    };

    textarea.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => {
      textarea.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, [textareaRef.current]);
```